# Java program will not connect to mySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

Using a simple example online, I am running a Java program to return users from a table.

The database is MySQL. I have already downloaded the JDBC driver, stored it in my JRE7 /lib folder.

The problem is the program never connects to the database, it skips the whole try block and prints out a "test" string at the end. Have I overlooked a major step in this? It's really frustrating!!

EDIT: Best to describe how I've attempted to set up a connection to the database.

The mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin is stored in jre7/lib.

I startup mysql workbench. The connection is name ive created is com.fyp.db, with the host address at 127.0.0.1:3306.

I then run my code, which attempts to query the sample table - sakila -  provided by mySQL workbench and..nothing!

Installed MySQL workbench. Installed JDBC driver.

```
public class Version {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    //String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/sakila";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from ACTOR;");

        System.out.println("test");

        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Its not skipping the try block, otherwise it would print the error. Tip: Add more System.out.println(...) to find out what is going on.

Comment: why are you sure that you did not connect to the databse? Maybe "test" is in the first column of the first row of the resultSet?

Comment: It is for sure skipping the try block, ive added some "test" strings in there since and they are not printed out.

Comment: @Jnanathan Please update your code to show it with the new "test" strings and also the console output.

Comment: @Jnanathan The try block will either complete normally or fail miserably - thats the idea. If you are encountering errors print the exception (ex), not "Error"

Comment: Can't you debug your code, to see how it goes on?

Comment: Only printing "Error" in those catch blocks deprives you of valuable debugging info. Replace those System.out.println("Error") statements with ex.printStackTrace() and report back with the results.

Comment: @Jnanathan: code shown very basic, you definitely should show us (or at least see by yourself) stack trace.

Comment: Guys, I've updated the code with added stack traces, which I have run myself. They are never called, which leads me to believe the problem might lie away from the code.

Comment: I've updated the description of my problem to explain the steps I've taken in attempting to create the connection. I feel as though I may have missed something along the way that someone may be able to spot.

Comment: Since the code itself looks OK and the exceptions aren't getting hit, can you provide details on exactly how you're running this program, such as the exact command line or whatever?

Comment: I've added a description on my installation. As for running the program, I start mySQL workbench, compile my java class and run it from the command line.

Comment: You still haven't revealed your actual command line.  I tried compiling your code (albeit to hit my own database table and minus the Class.forName line), then ran it with "java -classpath .:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar Version" - it returned the exact result I was expecting.  So, I'm thinking either something's wrong with your command line, or something's wrong with your JDBC driver.

Comment: On trying this again the program is now throwing up a noClassDefinitionFoundError? Im unsure what the class might be in this case as the java class compiles ok.

Comment: For the THIRD time, what is the exact command line you're using to run your program?  And what is the exact path to that mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar file? This is the last time I'm going to ask you for details. Without such info, I'm done, sorry.

Comment: Apologies, I could have sworn I included this in the last message.the command is: javac Version.java to compile, and to run: java Version, and the class path for the mysqlconnector is in the CLASSPATH environemnt variable, C:\Program Files\Java\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18;

Comment: OK, let's see if specifying the MySQL driver jar directly on the command line helps. Assuming the current directory is the one containing your source Version.java, compile with "javac -cp 'C:\Program Files\Java\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar' View.java" and then run with "java -cp '.:C:\Program Files\Java\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar' View" - make sure that MySQL driver jar is named exactly as it is on your system. I'm unsure of the exact name as you've given different names here.

Comment: A 'file not found' error for the mysql connector is returned when trying to compile the source code. When you say I have given different names for my MySQL driver, I dont understand?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8889/discussion-between-brian-showalter-and-jnanathan)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this line:

```
Class.forName("org.mysql.Driver");
```

before calling DriverManager.getConnection(...);

Comment: Only pre JDBC 4.0 and if that were the case it would throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should create new driver instance. Here's how:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Comment: Only pre JDBC 4.0 and if that were the case it would throw an exception.

Comment: @AleksandrKravets - the OP clearly states that wasn't the result. `getConnection()` would throw a `SQLException` if that were the case, and his code would print `Error`

Comment: Only thing i can assume now is mentioned "test" message was first value of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `jdbc.drivers` property is set. There are a variety of ways to do this,

see [the javadocs for DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple .. you need .jar file called mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar ,,, download it and add it to your libs ...

good luck !!!